# htaccess redirect virtual alias to url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a php page:

```
www.mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder/thepage.php
```

I want to access it via:

```
www.mydomain.com/page
```

How is that possible using the .htaccess file?!
I want to use an alias or virtual name to replace the long directory url.

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page$ /subfolder/subfolder/thepage.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
Redirect 302 /page /subfolder/subfolder/thepage.php
```